# Using Advanced Custom Fields in a widget

Tags: widgets, advanced-custom-fields

I've built a widget to show pages from a certain category in a dropdown menu. The page that's selected will show up on the homepage. This all works, except the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) are all showing the same image. I think it's to do with $instance...

The code I'm using is:

```
    <div class="home-image-box">

    <?php $attachment_id = get_field('main_image');
    $size = "home-boxes";
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size );
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($instance['post_id']); ?>">
    <img class="headline" width="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[2]; ?>" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
    </a>
    </div>

    <p class="extra-text"><?php the_field('sub_title'); ?></p>
```

All the code works great on the individual pages - it's just when called by the widget that I get these issues. The title and permalink are using the normal Wordpress functions, and these work fine too.

Are there any ACF users here that can shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to a "widget" (`/wp-admin/widgets.php`) or to an ACF *meta box* showing up in `/wp-admin/post.php?post=POST_ID`? In what theme template is this code happening? How are you re-using it?

Comment: To a widget. Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/kgm3cL7v

It's a custom built theme (if that's what you meant?).

Comment: Gah - I was looking too deeply into this... Passing postID as the second parameter works perfect.Thanks so much! Do you want to make this as an answer so I can accept it as solved?

Comment: Dave, when there are more than two commenteers, you have to address the other party like: @dalbaeb, so he/she receives a notification in the inbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the post ID as the second parameter:

```
the_field('sub_title', $instance['post_id']);
```